# After updating Ubuntu to 16.04 due to driver issues, NetBeans and Eclipse have stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, java, eclipse, ide

I just updated from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and it was a bumpy ride with damaged drivers along the way, probably because of the fact that 14.04 was missing two important drivers that 16.04 did have.

Now after restoring my drivers and a lot of systems I have a problem: whenever I create a new Java class in NetBeans or Eclipse my system hangs and the IDE becomes unresponsive. I can create empty files just fine and I can load and run files already created but I can no longer create new classes. I have correctly installed Java. I have also tried purge and install NetBeans and download and use a new version of Eclipse (Mars 1)

Any idea what's wrong? Or how to get useful information for debugging/solving the issue?

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 15.04 or 16.04? Ubuntu 16.04 is not scheduled for release until 21 April 2016, which is about 9 weeks from now. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/10/ubuntu-16-04-release-schedule-release-schedule-date-xenial-xerus

Comment: No 14.04 dev build.

Comment: could this be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764 ? I experience similar problems, and launchpad should be the right place to get it fixed by Ubuntu. Best regards,
mifritscher

Comment: Could be, however I'm not sure what I did but after reinstalling half my system (desktop manager, graphics driver, apt and a few others) it started working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me setting the environment variable `SWT_GTK3=0` worked. This is described in http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#gtkstartup.